# Chrome development tools grid wrong

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm not able to find the options where I could adjust the chrome dev tools device mode grid. It somehow got very wide (2800px) and I need it to get back to 2000px back again. Seems like a stupid question, but I'm stuck here...
Thanks in advance.

[image: Chrome grid too wide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum it puts one pixel per pixel on the screen. To make the window smaller just shrink the window you are inspecting with the []fit box checked, and the axis will rescale.